# Ajax call after postback in jquery function in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having problem for Ajax call from Jquery function after postback in mvc3. The action method mentioned in the ajax section below doesn't get called after postback whereas it works fine before postback.
    actually I am trying to get value for textbox. here is my Jquery function..

```
  $("#ddlDiagnosis").change(function () {
            alert($("#ddlDiagnosis").val());
            var selection = $("#ddlDiagnosis").val();
            var datatosend = { selectedValue: selection };

            $.ajax({
                url: "home/GetDiagnosisICDCode",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { selectedValue: $(this).val() },  //datatosend,
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var elements = "";
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $("#txtICDCode").val(this.ICDcode)
                    })
                }
            });

       });
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the value in the textbox after full postback? Then why you need an ajax call there? you can get the value from the posted form collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change URL like this

```
url: "/home/GetDiagnosisICDCode",
```

and `GetDiagnosisICDCode` must be public method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force to make ajax calls after a postback as the **state of the page is changing after the full postback**. So it wont happen. The function which is containing the ajax call should be executed to make the ajax request. For this you may use jquery's `$(document).ready(function(){});`Encapsulate your method using jquery's Initialization function. In a sequence, say you can make an ajax call first then you can make a full postback. But the reverse is not possible by maintaining the state of the page.